# Adding to a int value with pre-existing dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I am trying to set up a function that will calculate a score for the similarity of two films.  There are pre-existing dictionaries that with the films as keys and either the directors, genres, or main actors are values.  There are three actor dictionaries (the 3 lead actors for each film is listed).  The code mostly works fine but sometimes I get a resulting score greater than what I should get.

```
# create a two-variable function to deterime the FavActor Similarity score: 
def FavActorFunction(film1,film2):

    #set the result of the FavActor formula between two films to a default of 0.
    FavActorScore = 0
    #add 3 to the similarity score if the films have the same director.
    if direct[film1] == direct[film2]:
        FavActorScore += 3
    #add 2 to the similarity score if the films are in the same genre.
    if genre[film1] == genre[film2]:
        FavActorScore += 2
    #add 5 to the similarity score for each actor they have in common.
    if actor1[film1] == actor1[film2] or actor2[film2] or actor3[film2]:
        FavActorScore += 5
    if actor2[film1] == actor1[film2] or actor2[film2] or actor3[film2]:
        FavActorScore += 5     
    if actor3[film1] == actor1[film2] or actor2[film2] or actor3[film2]:
        FavActorScore += 5
    #print the resulting score.                    
    return FavActorScore
```

my assumption is that in counting the actors that they have in common, it is counting some things twice.  is there a way to revise this part of the code so it comes out with a more accurate result?

```
if actor1[film1] == actor1[film2] or actor2[film2] or actor3[film2]:   
    FavActorScore += 5
if actor2[film1] == actor1[film2] or actor2[film2] or actor3[film2]:  
    FavActorScore += 5     
if actor3[film1] == actor1[film2] or actor2[film2] or actor3[film2]:  
    FavActorScore += 5
```

Comment: I really, *really* have to ask: Where are these goofy data structures coming from? The film should be the dictionary, and the attributes should be the keys (and the actors should be in a sequence or set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the `in` condition :

```
if actor1[film1] in (actor1[film2], actor2[film2], actor3[film2]):
   FavActorScore += 5 
if actor2[film1] in ( actor1[film2], actor2[film2], actor3[film2]):
   FavActorScore += 5
if actor3[film1] in (actor1[film2], actor2[film2], actor3[film2]):
   FavActorScore += 5
```

When you write `a==b or c or d` this is true if a is equal to b or if c is true or if d is true not true if a is equal to b or c or d.